# Am having trouble in git push heroku master am getting the error below

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

```
rakesh@rakesh:~/rails/sapwii$ git push heroku master
Fetching repository, done.
Counting objects: 29, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (19/19), done.
Writing objects: 100% (19/19), 58.09 KiB, done.
Total 19 (delta 15), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.0.0
-----> Installing dependencies using 1.6.3
       Ruby version change detected. Clearing bundler cache.
       Old: ruby 2.0.0p481 (2014-05-08 revision 45883) [x86_64-linux]
       New: ruby 2.0.0p576 (2014-09-19 revision 47628) [x86_64-linux]
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/........
       Could not find activemerchant-1.43.2 in any of the sources
       Bundler Output: Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/........
       Could not find activemerchant-1.43.2 in any of the sources
 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !    
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app

To git@heroku.com:sapwii.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:sapwii.git'
```

I tried changing the SSH Keys and on heroku, getting this error only when pushing my core repository is fine to commit and clone

Answer (score 1):

From the error above, the error is caused by the active merchant version.  If you look at the [list of available versions for active merchant](https://github.com/Shopify/active_merchant/tags), you'll see that version 1.43.2 is not there. So either you upgrade or downgrade the version.  Check out your Gemfile and make sure that the version activemerchant is locked to exists.

If you didn't lock the activemerchant version in your Gemfile, just run `bundle update activemerchant` and that will fix your issue.